# Converting a list of objects to a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of city objects in which each object has a state and a name. I want to convert this list to a dictionary where the state name is the key and the value is a list of all the cities. For example,

```
"California" : [Ashland, Englewood, ...]
```

Right now I have

```
newDictionary = dict((x.state, x.name) for x in objectList)
```

but it is only adding the last city of each state instead of all of them. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Add sample input and output

Comment: Don't just re-describe your input in different but equivalent words in a comment, give us actual sample input, as a valid Python literal, in your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try `setdefault`.

```
stateWithCities = {}
for x in cityDataList:
    stateWithCities.setdefault(x.state, []).append(x.name)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like this (with more Pythonic variable names :-)):

```
state_with_cities = {}
for x in city_data_list:
    state_with_cities[x.state] = state_with_cities.get(x.state, []) + [x.name]
```

Comment: Wow, not sure how I got stuck on this lol but thanks, worked exactly how I wanted.

Comment: This is not particularly efficient because it will keep constructing new lists, see `setdefault` solution for a more efficient option. The other choice is to look at `collections.defaultdict`.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't run across setdefault before!